# Is JNI_OnLoad normally used for Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm new to Android NDK, and I was reading [these tips](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#native_libraries) on the Android Developer site. It recommends using `JNI_OnLoad` to register your native methods, but doesn't give much detail on how to do that.

Searching [Google's NDK sample repo on GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk) only turned up one usage of `JNI_OnLoad`, and it doesn't call `RegisterNatives`. Searching the web didn't turn up much on how to do this either.

I feel like I'm missing something. This is supposed to be the correct way to do it, according to Google, but their own examples use the "discovery" method naming approach instead.

Is this perhaps an old way of doing it, that's not really done anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**RegisterNatives** is fully supported on Android, and the proper way to do it is from **JNI_OnLoad**, which also works well and is [shown prominently in NDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#native_libraries). There are few reasons to use **RegisterNatives** vs. the usual automatic resolution of native methods through name matching (*always use **javah** to get correct names*).

1. When you have *many* of native methods, you may not want to have a huge exported function table in your shared library.
2. Using automatic matching makes reverse engineering and hacking your shared library easier.
3. You can build custom logic to match native methods at runtime.
4. [`@CriticalNative`](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/improvements#faster-native-methods) methods must be registered with **RegisterNatives** instead of relying on dynamic JNI linking.

None of these reasons apply to how-to samples and introductory tutorials.

Comment: Yes, the link you provided is to the same part of the documentation I was referring to. I'll update my link to point directly to that subsection. There are a lot of details missing, though, and I've been unable to turn them up in my online searches; which has led me to wonder why that's the case. Can you point me to a detailed example or tutorial where `JNI_OnLoad` is used? I will accept this answer, though, as it answers the question as stated. Thanks for the insights.

Comment: not a tutorial, but lots of opensource: [simple](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SimpleJNI) or [more advanced](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/modules/audio_device/android/audio_manager.cc).